# Compile error when combining lambda captures

Tags: c++, c++11

Someone asked me why this code does not compile:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    int x = 3, y = 2, z = 1;
    auto f = [&a,=]() { a = x + y + z; };
    f();
}
```

I've checked in Visual Studio 2017 and with wandbox for **gcc HEAD 8.0.0 201708** and it's true, it doesn't compile.

The first gcc error is just:

```
error: expected identifier before '=' token
```

on the line with the lambda, and it's complaining about the `=` in the capture clause.

What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For a lambda, default capture must be first.

```
auto f = [=, &a]() { a = x + y + z; };
```

#### [Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/AwmyLqqpLM0TzxxB)

Comment: There's a chance this changes for C++20: http://quuxplusone.github.io/draft/liberal-syntax-for-lambdas.html

Answer (score 5):

Just to complement Andy's answer, here's the standard reference:

[[expr.prim.lambda/1]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.prim.lambda#1)

> ```
> lambda-expression:
>     lambda-introducer lambda-declarator(opt) compound-statement
>
> lambda-introducer:
>     [ lambda-capture(opt) ]
>
> lambda-capture:
>     capture-default
>     capture-list
>     capture-default , capture-list
> ```

In particular, note that if the lambda capture contains both a default capture and a capture list, the grammar requires them to appear in the order above.